# Framer Studio, iOS Messages "select text"

Tags: ios, framerjs

With **Framer Studio**, I'm trying to replicate the **iOS Messages App's** "select text" feature as seen below:

[image]

Particularly, I want the **zoomed in bubble** to show up on any location when I press and hold.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example Chris Aga posted in the Framer.js Facebook group: http://share.framerjs.com/78aqs01eogh9/

So what you want to do is, first check for longpress:

```
screen.on Events.TouchStart, (event) ->
    isHeld = true
    Utils.delay .25, () ->
        if isHeld then triggerLongHold(event)
```

To normalize mouse and touch event coordinates we're using the [Pointer Module](http://framerco.de/post/130291848269/module-pointer-helper-class-this-module-helps-you). So you'll need to include the module in your project.
After that move the magnifying glass layer to wherever the long press is happening:

```
triggerLongHold = (event) ->
    mask.opacity = 1
    shadow.opacity = 1
    pointerValues = Pointer.screen(event, screen)
    mask.x = pointerValues.x - mask.width / 2
    mask.y = pointerValues.y - mask.height
    bgMagnified.x = -2 * pointerValues.x + 140
    bgMagnified.y = -2 * pointerValues.y + 120
```

and update its position if the user moves the finger/mouse:

```
    screen.on Events.TouchMove, (event) ->
        if isHeld
            pointerValues = Pointer.screen(event, screen)
            mask.x = pointerValues.x - mask.width / 2
            mask.y = pointerValues.y - mask.height
            bgMagnified.x = -2 * pointerValues.x + 140
            bgMagnified.y = -2 * pointerValues.y + 120
```

Hope this will get you started!